# Which ICC Profile should I use for my notebook screen (Toshiba Tecra)?

Tags: 12.04, toshiba, color-management

I have a dual monitor setup on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

1. the primary screen of my notebook **Toshiba Tecra R850-11D**
2. my external monitor **Samsung SyncMaster P2470HD**

The external monitor has a much better image quality, since it uses its own ICC Profile (Default, SyncMaster), but the screen of my notebook doesn't use any ICC Profile.

[image: Color]

What should I do and where could I get the appropriate ICC Profile for my Toshiba notebook in order to gain a much better quality of colors of my desktop environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate it yourself if you're willing to spend a bit of money and get a colorimeter.  Amazingly, there's one that's not only compatible with Linux, it's built ***for*** Linux!

[ColorHug](http://www.hughski.com/)

Use it with the *colorhug-client* package available in the repos.

This is really the best way as the colour profile is generated based on your own individual screen and even compensates for room lighting.

Otherwise, as you've seen if you do a Google search, colour profiles for something very specific are very hard to find and often don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to adjust colours is to create a script file that is auto-started when Ubuntu starts. Add the file to desktop, so you have manual access to it at all times.

The contents of the script should be 1 line:
"xgamma -rgamma 1.00 -ggamma 1.00 -bgamma 1.00"

you adjust the numbers up or down to suit your taste.

example:
 "xgamma -rgamma 1.10 -ggamma 0.90 -bgamma 0.60"

the terminal command is "xgamma".  you can add the "--h" option to read the help file.